# How can I change the height of a cylinder with "a-animation"?

Tags: animation, aframe

I want to increase the height of a `cylinder` on `aframe` as an animation.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use ngoKevins [animation component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/animation/):

1) either animate the scale:

```
animation__scale="property: scale; dir: alternate; dur: 200;
                       easing: easeInSine; loop: true; to: 1 2 1"
```

2) or animate the height:

```
animation__height="property: height; dir: alternate; dur: 200;
                       easing: easeInSine; loop: true; to: 3"
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/8t2td335/3/).

---

Using `<a-animation>` it would be like this:

```
<a-animation attribute="scale"
           dur="1000"
           direction="alternate"               
           to="1 2 1"
           repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
```

or

```
<a-animation attribute="height"
           dur="1000"
           direction="alternate"               
           to="3"
           repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/8t2td335/5/)